# error deploying C# project with sql database : unable to open physical file

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-deployment

I am deploying C# windows application with an sql server database

This is the error I get when I deploy:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It says your database file is missing. Make sure you deploy the database file with your project.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) for more information. If you have your MDB file as part of your project, make sure that its properties are set to be deployed, specifically the **Build Action** (set to *Content*) and **Copy to Output Directory**(set to *Copy if newer*) properties. Your requirements may vary though.

Comment: how to deploy database file with my project
also there is some images that does not appear in the program how to fix these problems

Comment: Answer reworked a little bit. You'd want to make sure that the suggestions above are applicable to your needs.